# Using transfinite induction to split $R$ to continuum many pairwise disjoint subsets of $R$

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

I am looking for different ways to partition $R$. I know some like :

(1) Define a relation as following $$x\sim y \ \text{iff} \  x-y\in\mathbb Q(x,y\in\mathbb R)$$. The equivalence classes have the form $[r]=r+\mathbb Q$ and clear they are countable dense and pairwise disjoint and $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb R} [r]$.

(2) Let $P$ be the family of all nonempty perfect subsets of $\mathbb R$ so $|P\times\mathbb R|=c.$ Then we can enumerate $P\times\mathbb R$ as follows $\{<P_{\xi},y_{\xi}>\colon\xi<c\}$.
Notice that each perfect will appear $c$ many time as first pair. We will construct by induction on $\xi$ a 
 sequence $\{x_\xi\colon \xi<c\}$ such that

$$x_{\xi}\in P_{\xi}\setminus\{x_{\zeta}\colon \zeta<\xi\}$$

Since each $x_{\lambda}\neq x_{\xi}$ for all $\lambda<\xi$ so we can define $f$ on $\{x_\xi\colon \xi<c\}$ such that $f(x_{\xi})=y_{\xi}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise, Thus, $f$ has a desired  property. It is not hard to see $f^{-1}(r)$ for each $r\in\mathbb R$ and  perfect set $P$ we have  $$f^{-1}(r)\cap P\neq\emptyset$$ and $$f^{-1}(r)\cap (R\setminus P)\neq\emptyset$$ $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb R} f^{-1}(r).$ Notice that $f^{-1}(r)$ is dense as well. $c$ is the cardinality for $\mathbb R.$

(3) Also, in John C, Oxtoby, Measure and Category, $\mathbb R$ can be written as union of meager set and null set.
My question is I want to see more interesting partition by using transfinite induction. Please Share you your ways if you know some. Thank in advance.

Comment: In (2) each $f^{-1}(r)$ is non-Lebesgue-measurable because neither it nor its complement has an uncountable closed subset, so it and its complement each has inner Lebesgue measure $0$....

Comment: There exists $\{G(r): r\in \Bbb R\}=G$ such that (i)  $\cup G=\Bbb R,$ (ii) $G(r)\cap G(r')=\phi$ when $r\ne r',$ (iii) if $D$ is any closed uncountable subset of $\Bbb R$ and $r\in \Bbb R$ then $|D\cap G(r)|=c.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, Thank you. (2) satisfies the conditions in you partition . but I would love to see the way that you did this construction

Comment: I have to re-write my A as it is unsound , so for now it  is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a few fairly strong such partition results are known. A few can be found in the following references, and googling their titles will give you many more: [*Sur une décomposition d'un intervalle en une infnité non dénombrable d'ensembles non mesurables*](https://mathoverflow.net/a/119693/15780) by Luzin/Sierpiński (1917), [*Sur la décomposition de l'espace euclidien en ensembles homogènes*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02020326) by Erdős/Marcus (1957; [Zbl review](https://www.emis.de/classics/Erdos/cit/07907802.htm)), [**Point Set Theory**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0824781783) by John Clifford Morgan (1990; see p. 152-154, pp. 245-248, and the references he gives), [*A nonmeasurable partition of the reals*](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bbms/1102714030) by Paula Ann Kemp (2001).

Regarding applications of transfinite induction for results such as your (1)-(3), you'll find a huge number by looking page-by-page through the earliest volumes (1920s and 1930s) of the journal [**Fundamenta Mathematicae**](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.bwnjournal-journal-fm).

Comment: L.Renfro That's great  references. Since I have zero knowledge of  Polish or French so I can not follow them. Do you know one find them by English?

Comment: @00GB: I am not aware of any translations into English of either of the two papers in French. Indeed, there are several hundred papers by Luzin and/or Sierpiński in French that I would like to have translations of, but my level of French is very, very poor. Despite this, I've taken it upon myself to prepare LaTeX translations of a few of their papers (but not their co-authored 1917 paper), but each of these took me many hours over a period of a week or two.

Comment: I have posted question about badly Darboux function Could you please check my post and give a hint if you could. I tried many times  but I got no thing . This my post "Continuous function with some properties plus everywhere surjective function must be everywhere surjective"