# Can $\mathbb{R}$ be written as an uncountable union of disjoint uncountable subsets?

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers

Can $\mathbb{R}$ be written as an uncountable union of disjoint uncountable subsets?

I was thinking of the following: Consider an uncountable proper subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{R}$, then consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $F$. If we accept the axiom of choice, this vector space has a basis, say, $B=\left\{b_\alpha:\alpha\in I\right\}$.

However, I am not sure if $B$ itself can be uncountable. If it can, we may consider the sets
$$
S_\alpha=\left\{\operatorname{span}_F(b_\alpha)\setminus\left\{0\right\}: \alpha\in I\right\}
$$
Then $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha\in I}S_\alpha \subset \mathbb{R}$, and we can easily obtain the desired form.

Comment: Your $B$ may be a singleton.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum).

Comment: For some decompositions that go a bit beyond purely set-theoretic constructions (in size and/or in "naturalness"), see my answer to [Using transfinite induction to split $R$ to continuum many pairwise disjoint subsets of $R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3597081/13130) *AND* [A partition of the unit interval into uncountably many dense uncountable subsets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463601/13130) *AND* my answer to [Are there sets of zero measure and full Hausdorff dimension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1647858/13130).

Comment: About your side question on the cardinality of $B$ (of course with AC), for a cardinal $\kappa$ the following are equivalent: 1) there is a subfield $F\subseteq \Bbb R$ such that $\dim_F(\Bbb R)=\kappa$; 2) $\kappa=1\lor \aleph_0\le \kappa\le \lvert \Bbb R\rvert$.